# Are there advantages for starting Elder Scrolls Online before they drop the subscripton fee?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

With the announcement that Elder Scrolls Online is dropping their subscription fees in the middle of March 2015, is there any advantage to getting into the game before the cutover?

Some games have perks and things for folks who were in the game before it went free (yes, ESO is going to a buy the game and play model not a true freemium model, so that might make a difference here.)

Does ESO offer any perks, items, etc. for playing it before it drops the subscription fee?

Comment: They *just* announced they were going free to play.  I don't believe we can answer this at this point in time.

Comment: Based on previous games that have done this sort of thing, I wouldn't expect much. Maybe a small amount of virtual currency to tempt you into spending real money on in-game items.

Comment: While they just announced this change, it's not really about "unreleased content". If you consider the payment model switch to be the "release", this question will no longer matter (and I actually consider it a good question for those being interested in the game).

Comment: Take a look at [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/wiki/f2p), it may help.

Comment: I guess I am confused about what is unreleased here? I understand that there isn't a lot of readily available info on this right now, but that is why I asked the question in the first place. I would like to know if there is a reason to start the game before March or not, and that seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct or massive advantage other than you being able to play right now. You will get 100 crowns extra for every month of subscription you've had so far, but since you can't get any (the initial free month won't count and you can't subscribe for 30 days before the deadline), that's a no now.

Any 30 days of subscription time after the "conversion date" will earn you 1500 crowns, but so does an active subscription you start at a later time.

Both points are mentioned in the official FAQ right now sitting on the [front page of their support page](https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/app/home):

> 2) As a current subscriber: If you are an active subscriber when **The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited** launches, you will receive 500 crowns for having a game account, plus 100 crowns for each 30-day period you have been an active subscriber. In addition, you'll be automatically enrolled in ESO Plus for the remainder of your subscription period. You'll receive the full benefits of membership, and 1500 crowns for each 30-day period remaining on your subscription. For example, if you have 30 days or less remaining, you will receive 1500 crowns. If you have between 30 and 60 days remaining, you will receive 3000 crowns. 60 to 90 days, 4500 crowns.

However, you might be able to grab a cheap copy of the old box before it's rereleased, which might be more expensive (but also contain more content on the actual DVDs). So if you're on a slower bandwidth, waiting might still be better, even if the new boxes are more expensive.